# display query value in lable in html body

Tags: html, mysqli, bootstrap-4

i want to display my query result in lable but in html body. i have counted records and want to display count result in lable.

here is my code

```
<div class="huge" >
<label class="pull-right" >
<?php
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root", "", "db1");
  $query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl1");
  $query->execute();
  $query->store_result();
  $rows = $query->num_rows;
  echo $rows;
?>
</label>
</div>
```

it returns value 1 whereas table is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Even your table is empty, it will return a row with a value of 0.
You are doing a number of rows, so it is returning 1 always.

Instead of this you should select everything and should count the results. (this is one solution).

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl1";
```

Answer (score 0):

you are mixing two approaches.

If you do

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM tbl1
```

it will return one value that is the number of records. So you just need to read the 1*1 array and you will get the result:

```
$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
echo $rows[0];
```

If you do

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1
```

it will return the full set of records fromt tbl1 (you can choose some fields of course). In this case to have the number of records you need to do

```
$rows = $query->num_rows;
```

that is not necessary in the previous option.

If your goal is just to know the number go for option 1. If you want to know the number and also use the records then go for option 2 since you will get both things with just one query

Comment: i am sorry i am confused by ur ans. i do not get what i have to do kindly review my code again

Comment: Read carefully my answer and you will get two different ways to do it